# Why does spring-data-redis ZSetOperations range operations return Set instead of SortedSet?

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis, zset

`ZSET`s are used to store sorted sets in redis. I am using `spring-data-redis` for ZSetOperations.

All the range methods return `Set<>` instead of `SortedSet<>` and I was wondering what's the reasoning behind it?

See : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ZSetOperations.java#L207

Also, since these don't return sorted sets, doesn't all the *reverse* range operations become redundant, since the order is not maintained anyway and we can not just get any element at an index?

I could be missing something very obvious, please excuse my naivete in the matter.

---

My use case :

I am storing values with dates as score. I want get all the values between two dates, check the count, and use the most recent date.

I was planning to do something like :

```
// get reverse sorted values, with most recent date being on top 
SrotedSet<String> values = zSetOperations.rangeByScore(key, this.getBeginDate(), this.getEndDate());
// check values size and do values.get(0) i.e. the most recent date.
```

But the return type of `rangeByScore` is `Set`, so no 'get' operations.

- I'll have to get the range with score and then sort them myself.
- Or I'll have to convert to array and get the element.
- Or do something like `values.iterator().next()`

Comment: I have this question now, 3 years later... Why indeed there is a set returned instead of some ordered collection?

Comment: @Neil If you ever find out, maybe 3 years later this question can be closed :)